# ref keyword with C++/CLI code interface

Tags: windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I'm writing code for the Windows Phone 8, and I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of  crossing the C#/C++ code barrier.

Let's say I have two `float[]` arrays on the C# side, we'll call them `data1` and `data2`. I want to perform an element-by-element addition on them.  As this is in a realtime system, (audio processing) I don't want to risk doing allocations and deallocations inside my audio processing routines, so I'll want something along the lines of `data1[i] += data2[i]`.  Since I'm explicitly learning how to call C++ from C# though, I won't just write the for loop in C#, I will write it in C++, like so:

```
void LibFilter::mixIn( Platform::Array<float>^ * data1, const Platform::Array<float>^ data2 ) {
    auto outArray = (*data1);

    // Don't do anything if we don't have matching lengths
    if( data2->Length != outArray->Length )
        return;

    // Sum data2 into outArray (which is just a dereferenced data1)
    for( unsigned int i=0; i<outArray->Length; ++i ) {
        outArray[i] += data2[i];
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work to me, but then again, I'm a C++ programmer, not a C# programmer, and apparently this should be used with the `out` keyword in C#, which means that `data1` is a null pointer, no matter the value passed in.  I believe I want to use the `ref` keyword instead, but I can't figure out how to do that using the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Suggestions on how to use the `ref` keyword here, or how best to architect this would be much appreciated, as I am still learning best practices with C#.  Thank you all!

**EDIT: Error information**

If I just try to use `libfilter.mixIn( ref data1, data2 );` from my C# code, I get the following:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'libfilter.LibFilter.mixIn(out float[], float[])' has some invalid arguments
error CS1620: Argument 1 must be passed with the 'out' keyword
```

Comment: What can't you figure out about using the ref keyword? Did you tried it and it failed? What error do you get?

Comment: I have updated the question with more information

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, it seems that the metadata that the C++/CX compiler generates for the method uses the **out** keyword, not the **ref** keyword.

Anyway, I don't see why you need to pass by reference at all. Platform::Array is mutable, so you can just modify it even if it's passed by value. The following MSDN article has an example similar to your code (see the section "Fill arrays"):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700131.aspx

Comment: Platform::Array's are not mutable, because they must be passed as either `const Array`, `Array *` or `WriteOnlyArray`.  In the first and third cases, I cannot modify elements, in the second case the array is not initialized.  This is why I was looking for an equivalent of the **ref** keyword, because apparently WinRT only supports **in** and **out**

Comment: Well the MSDN sample uses WriteOnlyArray to do what you want.

Comment: No, it doesn't. In the example, the value of `arr` is only ever assigned to, it is never read from. I want to use `+=`, not just `=`